# Object.memberFunction(argument).MemberFunction(); - I just don't get this

Tags: c++

I am working on a bigger assignment - a fictional internet banking database. All's okayish, only it needs to be able to respond to a call like this:

```
bank.Account("123456").Balance();
```

bank is an instance of a class Bank which holds an array (yep, I am forbidden to use most of the STL) of objects of the class Account.

Thoughts: I need a function Account & Account ( const char * ) in the class Bank that would be a friend function for the class Account and then it is possible to call the Balance function that is declared in the Account class. 
Am I doing this right? I am not really asking you to write the code for me, I only want to know if I am headed in the right direction. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the right direction. Your Bank class needs a public method

```
Account& Account (const char*);
```

And your Account class needs the public function

```
int Balance();
```

Actually you do not need "friend" in order to access the methods, they just have to be public.

Be careful about your Account method though. If you enter an account name that does not exist, what will you return? Perhaps you should return in this case an empty Account object (needs to be a member of your Bank class though). In this case, you should check your returned Account object if it is valid before calling Balance().

Answer (score 2):

> I need a function Account & Account ( const char * ) in the class Bank that would be a friend function for the class Account and then it is possible to call the Balance function that is declared in the Account class. Am I doing this right?

You don't need any `friend` class or function, just make the getters `public`:

```
class Bank {
public:
    Account & Account ( const char * );
};

class Account {
public:
    Balance& Balance();
};
```

Comment: did this and it solved a lot, only now I am having a problem where the Account function is fighting with the Account constructor. Ah. A lot of work ahead of me.

Comment: @LeaPetrášová The usual way to handle a non existing account (no match is found for the string), is to throw an exception. You can also have a dummy `Account` class member in your `Bank` class, that indicates itself as invalid (e.g. has an id -1), and return a reference to that one in case no matching account is found.

Answer (score 1):

The pseudo-code in your title should probably be `object.MemberFunction1(arguments).MemberFunction2()`. And it's all okay, it will work fine.

If `MemberFunction1` returns an object, or a reference to an object, you can then chain on more calls to the returned object (or reference). And the classes don't have to be friends, if they are not trying to access and non-public members.

In fact, if the returned object contained a method which in turn returned an object, then you could have

```
object.MemberFunction1(arguments).MemberFunction2().MemberFunction3();
```

And so on and so on.

Comment: Yay that's cool! Had no idea about this. I actually need to access the private members - Account IDs, so that's why. Or I could use a getter - I am not really sure what's the difference, only I feel like -etters are lazy.

Comment: @LeaPetrášová If you *need* private members you should probably rethink your design. Worst case, you add getter/setter function (functions that only gets or sets these private variables), best case you redesign the classes to minimize this access.